Can every registered gitlab user authenticate through a user-owned application?
I have user access (not admin access) to a gitlab instance. I want all users registered in this gitlab instance to be able to log into my application that runs elsewhere using oidc.
What I don't really understand from the descriptions is: when I configure a user-owned application as described here can everybody registered in the gitlab instance access my application or can only I (as the user who configured the application) use the gitlab instance to log into my application?
To deepen my understanding: if everybody registered with the gitlab instance can use it to log into my (user owned) application (as I hope and intend it to be), what could be a reason to create a group owned (or "instance owned") application in the gitlab instance? What additional features are provided with respect to oidc authentication to an application when it is "group owned" instead of "user owned"?

I don't know why somebody wants to close this question. The answer is not obvious and e.g. ChatGPT (3.5) is completely wrong: "When you configure a user-owned application in GitLab using OpenID Connect (OIDC), it typically means that only you, as the user who configured the application, can use the GitLab instance to log into your application. Other users registered in the GitLab instance won't be able to use it to log into your application unless they configure their own user-owned applications with similar settings."

I tested this today with the help of a colleague. Obviously, everybody who has an account on the gitlab instance can use it to log into a user-owned application that uses this gitlab instance as identity provider.
The test didn't answer the second part of the question about the differences between a user-owned, group-owned and instance owned-application. My assumption is that a group-owned application can be granted access to scopes (resources) that only exist for groups (and similar for instance-owned application). This, however, is only important if you want to access gitlab resources from the application (oauth use case). It doesn't make a difference when you only want to use gitlab as an identity provider (oidc use case).
